# nested requests in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Is it possible to call a function inside an action method that will eventually generate a new (aka nested) request to the same server?

This comes up because I am trying to use the evohtmltopdf pdf converter to combine several pdfs into one. The problem: The individual pdfs are also generated by the same server.

The snippet from my action method below creates an error message indicating that the converter can't fetch the /Attachment/Pdf doc while still handling the current request.

```
    // create pdfDocument with main content retrieved from RenderViewToString output
    // [...]
    // Now add appendixes by handing converter urls and letting it fetch the docs. 
    UrlHelper url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Request.RequestContext);
    HtmlToPdfElement attachment = new HtmlToPdfElement(0, 500, url.Action("Pdf", "Attachment");
    pdfDocument.Pages[summary.LastPageIndex].AddElement(attachment);
```

Is this really not possible and if so, how do I get around the restriction?
Duffy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was somewhere else and the snippet above did work in the end.